# C# Stackoverflow Error in PCRE.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pcre, pcre.net

I use [PCRE.NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net) (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions for .NET) lib. I have a interesting error and have a two application. One is Asp.net APP and other one is Console APP. My Console APP is work good but Asp.net APP give error ( Stackoverflow )

What can I do for Asp.net App ?

**Console APP:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string test = "";

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            test = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var matches = PcreRegex.Matches(test, @"(\/\*(?:(?!\/\*).|(?1))*?\*\/)(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*CREATE |^\s*ALTER |^\s*DROP |^\s*GRANT ", PcreOptions.MultiLine | PcreOptions.Singleline | PcreOptions.IgnoreCase).ToList();

    }
```

**Asp.Net APP:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = "";

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            test = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var matches = PcreRegex.Matches(test, @"(\/\*(?:(?!\/\*).|(?1))*?\*\/)(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*CREATE |^\s*ALTER |^\s*DROP |^\s*GRANT ", PcreOptions.MultiLine | PcreOptions.Singleline | PcreOptions.IgnoreCase).ToList();            
    }
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in 420cc350a653e64458da2ef4f8e4ac89.dll

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: Hey there, I'm the lib author :) Interesting error you've got there, could you post more of the stack trace?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Firstly Thank you for this lib. I looked exception detail but there is a no more information. "{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}". How can I get detail error message ?

Comment: Hmm yes, the stack overflow completely breaks the app, and therefore the debugger... I'll try to reproduce this issue on my side but I can't give promises about the timeframe. I never tested it with ASP.NET, but I suspect this *might* be a LibZ+appdomains related issue.* Meanwhile, I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net/issues/5).

Comment: You could also try the following if you're willing to spend a few minutes: clone the PCRE.NET repository, build the solution in either x86 or x64 mode (depending on your platform), and reference the obtained `PCRE.NET.dll` **and** `PCRE.NET.Wrapper.dll` instead of the NuGet package in your ASP.NET solution. If this workaround works, it means it's a LibZ issue (I use it to package both assemblies into a single DLL, hence the GUID-looking DLL name in the error).

Comment: What are you trying to match with `(\/\*(?:(?!\/\*).|(?1))*?\*\/)`, is it C comments? If yes, why do you need a recursive pattern since comments can't be nested (the first `*/` close the comment even there are several `/*` before.)

Comment: For C comments, you only need: `/\*[^*]*+(?:\*+(?!/)[^*]*)*+(?:\*/|\z)` (no need to escape the slashes). And instead of `^\s*CREATE |^\s*ALTER |^\s*DROP |^\s*GRANT`, put the beginning in factor `^\s*(?:CREATE|ALTER|DROP|GRANT)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte , I use this pattern because of sql parsing and you can look https://regex101.com/r/oB7pA2/11

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I will try your method ( "clone the PCRE.NET repository, build the solution in either x86 or x64 mode" ) and then I will report you.

Comment: @Chicharito:Its what I believed, you don't need a recursion for C comments: https://regex101.com/r/nN2sC1/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are King :) Thank you for helping. Your pattern solved my problem and It is work great. But I want to ask you something. You will see SQL Insert statement ( CREATE_USERID ) in this https://regex101.com/r/nN2sC1/3 This is not match in regex101.com but it is match at PCRE.NET. You use "~" but I don't use this. Can you check my code ?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thank you for lib and help, CasimiretHippolyte code solved my problem.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Btw, I added space character that pattern and then my SQL Insert statment problem solved but is it true way ? 
(?:CREATE |ALTER |DROP |GRANT )

Comment: @Chicharito: delimiters like `~` `#` or `/` are only needed for some implementations like PHP (that's why when `/` is the delimiter you need to escape all slashes, but since you don't need delimiters, you don't need to escape them). About the space, if you look carefully the pattern, you can see that there's already a space after the non-capturing group. But instead of a space you can use something like `(?:CREATE(?:_USERID)?|ALTER|DROP|GRANT)\b`. As an aside, you should make a search about eventual SQL tokenizer/parser libraries.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, Thank you for all help. I solved all problem thanks to you and I am grateful to you.

Comment: @Chicharito you're welcome, but I still need to fix that stack overflow error, as it's a severe bug. I'll try to reproduce this issue when I'll have some time (and I'm not sure when that will happen). Thanks for the bug report anyway. BTW, since you posted a working recursive pattern in the question (which few people do), I assumed you required the pattern to be recursive.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You are right. I will clone the PCRE.NET repository, build the solution in either x86 or x64 mode and then debug for you. If I am here today I will look and write result in here.

Comment: @Chicharito thanks for your effort, but don't bother: I think I know what's going on. I realized that since Casimir's suggestion worked, it can't be LibZ fault as I thought. The problem simply comes from the fact that [IIS reserves 256KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/932909) of stack space instead of the *standard* 1MB, and your pattern uses all of that. I didn't test it but *maybe* the original pattern could work if you replace the first occurrence of `(?:` with `(?>` - in any case, that doesn't seem to be a library bug after all.